# ROOM Cannot figure out how to save this field into database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I need your help.
I try to find the solution without deserialize but I didn't find nothing.
It would be nice if you can help me...
So I have this following JSON file

```
"resources": [{
    "id": 441988,
    "name": "TVA",
    "parent": {
      "id": 159
    },
  },
  {
    "id": 441900,
    "name": "Marketing",
    "parent": {
      "id": 166
    },
}]
```

I used ROOM to create a database, it works but I have one problem,
its impossible to save "id of Parent object"

here is my following code :

```
    @Entity(tableName = "resources")
    class CategoryBean {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "resource_id")
    @SerializedName("id")
    private var mId: Int = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    @SerializedName("name")
    private var mName: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "parent")
    @SerializedName("parent")
    private var mParent: ParentBean? = null

    fun getId(): Int {
        return mId
    }

    fun getName(): String? {
        return mName
    }

    fun getParent(): ParentBean? {
        return mParent
    }

    fun setParent(parent: ParentBean) {
        mParent = parent
    }

    fun setId(id: Int) {
        mId = id
    }

    fun setName(name: String) {
        mName = name
    }
```

Here you can find my ParentBean file

```
class ParentBean {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private var mId: Int = 0

    fun getId(): Int? {
        return mId
    }

}
```

I found some solution for a list, but not for sub object.

thank you for your time and your help.

There is my following error :

```
Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Room works on top of a SQLite database, when you annotate a class as `@Entity` you are creating a table whose columns are defined according to the properties of the class, so you can't store directly a custom type like `ParentBean`, to do that, you need to annotate `mParent` property as `@Embedded`:

```
@Entity(tableName = "resources")
class CategoryBean constructor(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "resource_id")
    @SerializedName("id")
    var mId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    @SerializedName("name")
    var mName: String?,
    @SerializedName("parent")
    @Embedded
    var mParent: ParentBean?
)
```

Then you define a column name for the property in `ParentBean`:

```
data class ParentBean constructor(@SerializedName("id") @ColumnInfo(name = "parent_id")var mId: Int)
```

resources table will have the following columns: `resource_id`, `name`, `parent_id`

source: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data

Note: You don't need to manually define getter and setters in Kotlin.

Comment: It works, and thank you for the link.
Sometime parent can be null. 
So i have this following code :    
@Embedded
@SerializedName("parent")
private var mParent: ParentBean? = null
do you know why  I have this following error :
Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter parent

Comment: @AlainProfessional then you need to change `var mId: Int` to `var mId: Int?` in `ParentBean` data class

Comment: Oh ok thank you , by the way , by changing to data class, it solve the problem but thank you @glisu

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your JSON data is not valid.

```
"resources": [{
  "id": 441988,
  "name": "TVA",
  "parent": {
    "id": 159
  },            //This Line has a comma without another field following it
},
{
  "id": 441900,
  "name": "Marketing",
  "parent": {
    "id": 166
  },           //This Line has a comma without another field following it
}]
```

Also the entire thing should be surrounded by another set of curly braces (but I am assuming that was left out due to copy & paste).

A good tool to test out your JSON data and your POJOs is this site: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Hope this helps :)

Comment: sorry its because I didnt copy paste the Json correctly. I just delete some useless line, that why its not correct