# Embedded annotation can't save a list of data class into room database

Tags: android, database, android-room, data-class

I have a list for embedded data class and inside that, I have again another data class and when use @Embeded and @ColumnInfo for embedded column got this error:

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538271/room-cannot-figure-out-how-to-save-this-field-into-database/59951353#59951353) and answer and try it but got below error.

```
@Entity(tableName = "venues_table")
data class Venue(

    @Embedded
    val categories: List<Category>,

    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,

    @Embedded
    val location: Location,

    val name: String
)


data class Category(

    @Embedded
    val icon: Icon,

     @ColumnInfo(name = "id_category")
    val id: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name_category")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "plural_name")
    val pluralName: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "primary")
    val primary: Boolean,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "short_name")
    val shortName: String
)

e: error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - java.util.List
```

may please help me to fix this

Comment: `@Embedded` says "take the columns from this other entity's table and embed them in this entity's table". That only works for single entities, not collections. Use `@ForeignKey` and perhaps `@Relation` to set up a one-to-many relationship between `Venue` and `Category`.

Comment: I make it like this : @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "id_category"
    )
    val categories: List<Category>,      @Entity(foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
    entity = Venue::class,
    parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
    childColumns = arrayOf("id_category"),
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
)]
)
data class Category(     @PrimaryKey
     @ColumnInfo(name = "id_category")
    val id: String,   -- and get this error: Entities cannot have relations.
public final class Venue {

Comment: `@Relation` would go on some other object that your DAO returns. You cannot put it directly on an entity. See [these classes](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/tree/v0.1/MiscSamples/src/main/java/com/commonsware/room/misc/onetomany) for an example (described in greater detail in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Room)).

Comment: the list of data classes is inside the venue. and this is because of API for foursquare. not outside venue data class. and I had to keep list<category> inside the venue. all because I want to make cache for the time we have not internet access have last data and read from the database for user feed

Comment: Then, if you are going to use Room, you need different classes for talking to Foursquare than the classes that you use to talk to Room. Those are each DTOs (data transfer objects) and will need to meet specific requirements for the specific APIs that you are using. You might also have a third set of objects, representing the ideal view of the data from the standpoint of the app itself (independent of what Foursquare and Room require).

Answer (score 1):

you can't use "List" type in entities without type converter(see the official document https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data) you must use type converter for "List", "bitmap" etc. I wish It's useful for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).